# Posting 5 parameters with url to fetch data from API

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to fetch data from API using volley library but I don't know how to send parameter with volley request. I am not able to figure out whether to use Post Request or Get Request or Put Request.
 I am using the following code to make volley request

```
public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
}

public static void put(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    client.put(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
}
```

Here is my entire code :

```
     private void getCalendarEvents(String StartDate,String EndDate,String UserId,String CityID,String IsAdmin) {
    RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
    requestParams.put("StartDate", StartDate);
    requestParams.put("EndDate", EndDate);
    requestParams.put("UserId", UserId);
    requestParams.put("CityID", CityID);
    requestParams.put("IsAdmin", IsAdmin);

    RelayRestClient.put("CalendarGetEvents", requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if (responseBody != null)
                Log.e("success", new String(responseBody));
            parse(new String(responseBody));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            Log.e("failure", new String(responseBody));
        }
    });
}
        protected void parse(String s) {
                try {
                    JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(s);
                    if (mainObject.has("Status")) {

                        String Status = mainObject.getString("Status");
                        if (Status.equalsIgnoreCase("200")) {

                            if (mainObject.has("Data")) {
                                JSONArray datArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("Data");
                                eventBeanArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                                if (datArray.length() > 0) {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < datArray.length(); i++) {
                                        EventsBean eventsBean = new EventsBean();
                                        JSONObject internalDataObject = datArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                        if (internalDataObject.has("UserID")) {
                                            eventsBean.setUserID(internalDataObject.getString("UserID"));
                                        }
                                        if (internalDataObject.has("EventID")) {
                                            eventsBean.setEventID(internalDataObject.getString("EventID"));
                                        }
                                        if (internalDataObject.has("CityID")) {
                                            eventsBean.setCityID(internalDataObject.getString("CityID"));
                                        }
                                        if (internalDataObject.has("Title")) {
                                            eventsBean.setTitle(internalDataObject.getString("Title"));
                                        }
                                        eventBeanArrayList.add(eventsBean);
                                    }
                                    setViewEventData(eventBeanArrayList);
                                } else {

                                    showMessage("No Events found for this date.");
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            showMessage("Server error, Please try again");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
private void setViewEventData(ArrayList<EventsBean> eventBeanArrayList) {
    lv_events.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(ViewEventActivity.this,eventBeanArrayList));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HashMaps and post parameter by overriding the getParams method of your volley request. It should look something like this:

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //Handle Response

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //Handle volley Error

                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(key1,value1);
                params.put(key2,value2);
                params.put(key3,value3);
                params.put(key4,value4);
                params.put(key5,value5);
                return params;
            }

        };
```

Comment: @MohiniMonga My pleasure